# Regex for Google filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

My Google Analtyics is victim of Ghost Spam, in particular is something which looks like

`/?from=http://site-63162314-1.snip.tw/`
`/?from=http://site31946091.snip.tw/`
`/?from=http://site18623769.snip.tw/`

I'd like to create a regex which will match the following string: `site(something).snip.tw`

After a read up on a few sites of how to use Regex, my effort is

```
.*site.*snip
```

This only fiters out the last in the list above (`/?from=http://site18623769.snip.tw/`) but oddly, it also filters out other URLs, such as `?from=http://share-buttons.xyz/` (which is fine) but sadly so has `/MassageTherapy/DeepTissueMassage?cpc=dtm`

Why does my regex not match the above 3 examples?

Comment: It seems you used a wrong type of filter.

Comment: @stribizhev, does that mean my regex in this post appears to be valid?

Comment: It seems valid to me, although I'd just use `site.*snip[.]tw`.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Try following [`\s*http\:\/\/[\w\-\.]*snip\.tw`](https://regex101.com/r/eC8xN0/1)